# Vuejs deep nested computed properties

Tags: vue.js

I'm not really understanding where to put `function() { return {} }` and where not to when it comes to deeply nesting computed properties.

**By the way, this is in a component!**

```
computed: {
        styles: function() {
            return {
                slider: function() {
                    return {
                        height: {
                            cache: false,
                            get: function() {
                                return 'auto';
                            }
                        },
                        width: {
                            cache: false,
                            get: function() {
                                return $('#slideshow').width();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
```

This is returning undefined. When I get rid of the `function() { return {} }` inside of the slider index, it returns an object when I do `styles.slider.width` instead of the `get()` return. It just shows an object with cache and get as indexes..

Thanks for any help!

The reason I'm asking is because I have multiple nested components that involve styling from the parent. Slider, tabs, carousels, etc. So I wanted to organize them like this.

Comment: perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but are you trying `styles.slider.width.get()` or `styles.slider.width`? I don't think the latter will act as a getter unless you explicitly use Object.defineProperties.

Comment: You mention "deeply nesting computed properties". Why do you think something like that is possible? Computed properties don't support nesting: http://vuejs.org/guide/computed.html

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean to return a computed object, but not actually structure the computation in a nested manner?

What the others have said regarding the 'computed' hook not having syntax for nesting is correct, you will likely need to structure it differently.

This may work for you: I generate many objects in a similar fashion.

```
computed: {
   computedStyles(){
     var style = {slider:{}}
     style.slider.height = 'auto'
     style.slider.width = this.computedSlideshowWidth
     return style
   },
   computedSlideshowWidth(){
     return $('#slideshow').width()    
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

As per 2020 and Vue 2.6.12 this is completelly possible. I believe this has been possible since v.2 but cannot confirm.

Here is the working example:

```js
this.computed = {

    // One level deep nested, 
    // get these at `iscomplete.experience` 
    // or `iscomplete.volume`
    iscomplete: function() {
        return {
            experience: this.$data.experience !== null,
            volume: this.$data.volume > 100,
            // etc like this
        };
    },

    // More levels deep nested.
    // Get these at `istemp.value.v1 and `istemp.value.v2`
    istemp: function() {
        return {
            value1: {
                v1: this.$data.experience,
                v2: 'constant'
            }
        }
    }
    
};
```

As a result you will be able to access your deep nested computed in your template as e.g. follows `<span v-text="iscomplete.experience"></span>` that will output `<span>true</span>` for the first example computed above.

Note that:

1. Since Vue v.2 `cache` key is deprecated;
2. Vue would not execute functions assigned to a `computed` object nested keys;
3. You cannot have computed for non-Vue-reactive things which in your case is e.g. `$('#slideshow').width()`. This means they are not going to be re-computed on their content change in this case (which is a computed's sole purpose). Hence these should be taken away from `computed` key.

Other than that I find nested computeds to be quite helpful sometimes to keep things in better order.

Comment: @cezar :) I was glad to see you really care ) thanks

Comment: I liked the answer, but I would like to know if this can be combined with getters and setters.

Comment: @cezar I did not use it with getters as to my experience the entire approach is already too complex (nesting does borrow a lot from code clarity) and asks for simplification. So I changed my patterns to always very simple one level deep computed (proxy to store, boolean flag etc.). If I need computations they are done somewhere else (e.g. dedicated object). As for setters it is very rare use case for me. I again prefer to delegate the computations to some dedicated object instead of a setter.